# MySQL Crash on Fulltext search

Tags: mysql

After executing this specific query

```
SELECT * FROM product WHERE MATCH(description) AGAINST('+composi*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

**MySQL 5.6.26** crash with this log

```
Timestamp, Thread, Type, Details
2015-10-02 11:51:31, 1308, Note, C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
, , , Version: '5.6.26-log'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
, , , 2015-10-02 12:06:58 c18  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 3096 in file fts0que.cc line 3659
, , , InnoDB: Failing assertion: !query->intersection
, , , InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
, , , InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
, , , InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
, , , InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
, , , InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
, , , InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
, , , InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
```

Table `product` has 25'000'000 record with this config

```
CREATE TABLE `product` (
  `Id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `IdPrice` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Description` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
  KEY `Fk_IdPrice_idx` (`IdPrice`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `Idx_Description` (`Description`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=0 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Server environment:

```
Amazon EC2 t2.medium (2 CPU, 4GB RAM) 
Windows Sever 2012 R2
MySQL 5.6.26 (x86)
```

My.ini

```
[client]
no-beep
port=3306

[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysqld]
port = 3306
datadir=D:/MySQL_Data/Data
character-set-server=utf8
default-storage-engine=INNODB
sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
log-output=FILE
general-log=0
slow-query-log=1
server-id=1
max_connections=151
query_cache_size=1M
table_open_cache=2000
tmp_table_size=67M
thread_cache_size=10
myisam_max_sort_file_size=100G
myisam_sort_buffer_size=124M
key_buffer_size=8M
read_buffer_size=64K
read_rnd_buffer_size=256K
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=9M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1
innodb_log_buffer_size=5M
innodb_buffer_pool_size=405M
innodb_log_file_size=48M
innodb_thread_concurrency=8
innodb_autoextend_increment=64
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=8
innodb_concurrency_tickets=5000
innodb_old_blocks_time=1000
innodb_open_files=300
innodb_stats_on_metadata=0
innodb_file_per_table=1
innodb_checksum_algorithm=0
back_log=80
flush_time=0
join_buffer_size=256K
max_allowed_packet=4M
max_connect_errors=100
open_files_limit=4161
query_cache_type=1
sort_buffer_size=256K
table_definition_cache=1400
binlog_row_event_max_size=8K
sync_master_info=10000
sync_relay_log=10000
sync_relay_log_info=10000
ft_min_word_len = 2
general_log_file = "D:/MySQL_Log/general.log"
log-error = "D:/MySQL_Log/error.log"
lower_case_table_names = 2
```

How fix it?

Comment: Did you solve this? I am facing the same problem.

Comment: @najeira no... i have migrate the db to elastic search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have hit a bug. You can try:

- Upgrading MySQL to the latest version
- Downgrading MySQL to something fairly recent
- Check to see if the bug can be reproduced with your data on a different operating system
- Once you have the data on the above, see if you can isolate it to the minimal dataset, and then report the bug at http://bugs.mysql.com
- If that table does not have to be InnoDB, you can try `ALTER TABLE Product ENGINE=MyISAM` - this will likely work around the bug at the cost of losing transactional capabilities and row level locking in that table - which may be acceptable if you are careful. Fulltext support in MyISAM is 15 years old, in InnoDB it is still fairly new and all the bugs have not yet been worked out.